# How to save the context before await function in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm a newbie developer in NodeJS and backEnd, I have a problem in my KoaJS demo.

```js
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");
const cache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 300 });

app.use(async (message, ctx) => {
  var cacheKey = message.userName; // e.g. cacheKey = "Jeff"
  var result = await aSlowFunction(); // before this line finished, another request received, and the cacheKey will change to "Tom".
  cache.set(cacheKey, result); // This will be run after 2s, and the cacheKey will be changed to 'Tom' but 'Jeff' is the desired one here.
});

async function aSlowFunction(cacheKey) {
  // Will cost 2 s;
}
```

My problem is I found the cache will cache with a wrong cacheKey if there are many requests from clients in a short time.

I think the reason is because the cacheKey changed after another request received by the `app.use` so `cache.set(cacheKey, result);` will use a wrong  cacheKey.

Is there any simple mechanism in nodejs to handle this sistuation ? e.g. callback capture the cacheKey to use it after the `await` finished.

Something like

Comment: It's not really clear what problem you're trying to solve here.  Your `cacheKey` variable will accurately represent the value of `message.userName` at the start of your middleware before `aSlowFunction()` does anything.  That's exactly what your code does.  Your `cacheKey` variable will not be influenced by any other request handler as it's a private variable visible ONLY to this particular instance of this particular handler.  No other code or request can see that instance of your `cacheKey` variable.

Comment: Now, if the problem is that the value you put in `cacheKey` becomes invalid during the time that `aSlowFunction()` is running, then that's a different issue entirely and we'd need to know more about why that is and what key you want to be using in order to help any further.

Comment: Note, it's also possible that some other request modifies the cache entry for Jeff and then when `aSlowFunction()` completes, you overwrite the cached value for the Jeff key.  That's a matter of managing which entry you want cached, the request that arrived last or the one that finished last.

Comment: Do you mean that cacheKey before and after the `await line` will always be the same, my guess is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I mean your guess is wrong.  As illustrated in the code you show, nothing else can change the value of your `cacheKey` local variable that is a primitive string.  It is private to this instance of this running function.  So, for us to help you with whatever your actual problem is, you need to put aside your guess and describe the actual problem you observe.  Now, if in your real code, `cacheKey` was an object, then some other code could change properties on that object while `aSlowFunction()` was running.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to make sure cacheKey is stored with the result of aSlowFunction, then send it to aSlowFunction and return it.

```
var cacheKey = message.userName; // e.g. cacheKey = "Jeff"
var result = await aSlowFunction(cacheKey); 
cache.set(result.cacheKey, result.data);
```

and

```
async function aSlowFunction(cacheKey) {
  // Will cost 2 s;
  data = //whatever you're calculating
  return {
    data,
    cacheKey
  }
}
```

Comment: `cacheKey`  as a string primitive in the OP's code is a private local variable.  Nothing in some other request handler in the code they show will be able to change it while `aSlowFunction()` is running so this doesn't solve whatever the actual problem is.